# Query divides a column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scenario:
I have 2 columns, the first column is called AgentID and the second column is called AgentName in the agents table. Few AgentID starts with an "A" and few starts with an "M", what I want to do is the following:

```
AgentID AgentName
A123    Name1
M123    Name2
A234    Name3

Aagents AAgentName Magents MAgentName
A123    Name1      M123    Name2
A234    Name3      NULL    NULL
```

Is this possible? I know it is weird but my boss wants it to be this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH AAgents AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AgentID) AS RN,
         AgentID AS Aagents,
         AgentName As AAgentName
  FROM Agents
  WHERE LEFT(AgentID,1)='A'
),
MAgents As
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AgentID) AS RN,
         AgentID AS Magents,
         AgentName As MAgentName
  FROM Agents
  WHERE LEFT(AgentID,1)='M'
)

SELECT
  Aagents,
  AAgentName,
  Magents,
  MAgentName
FROM AAgents
FULL OUTER JOIN MAgents
ON AAgents.RN=MAgents.RN
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd984/3)

Comment: Your answer is very similar to mine but you used CTE instead of subqueries. Out of curiosity: what is the benefit of using CTE in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a full outer join between 2 subqueries (one for A agents, one for M agents) and join on `ROW_NUMBER()` to have nulls on one side (the one with less records):

```
select A.AgentID Aagents, A.AgentName AAgentName, M.AgentID Magents, M.AgentName MAgentName from
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AgentID) rn from Agents where AgentID like 'A%') A
full outer join
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by AgentID) rn from Agents where AgentID like 'M%') M
on A.rn = M.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select * from (select AgentID as Aagents, AgentName as AagentName from table where 
AgentID like 'A%'), (select AgentID as MAgents, AgentName as MAgentName from 
table where AgentID like 'M%')
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
select 
case when AgentName like 'A%' then name end as Aagents,
case when AgentName like 'M%' then Name end as Magents
from tblName
```